# What type of surge protector is appropriate for a service panel?

Tags: electrical

I'm looking to add a surge protector in my power panel.

I have researched on the different type 1 and type 2.
I have no preference of type.  Recommendations are much appreciate.
Researching my options, if I even have options.
My panel has a single opening at the bottom.

All help is appreciated.

Rick[image: Power Panel]

Answer (score 2):

> I'm looking to add a surge protector in my power panel.

Surge protectors don't require any breaker spaces, so that's not any kind of impediment.

> Researching my options, if I even have options. My panel has a single opening at the bottom.

Yeah, those all-in-one panels can be a real pain.  You'd need to find a surge that is listed for installing inside the panel enclosure, and then just pigtail it off the 20A breaker that's already in there.

If you just can't find a surge protector that is listed to be entirely inside an enclosure, then you're in luck because the guy who wired this panel left you enough wire to reach any position in the panel. So you could replace the 40 with an Eaton BR 20/40 quadplex, move the 20A 2-pole circuit down there, and then install a BRNSURGE in the 2 spaces formerly occupied by the 20A breaker.